# Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter' Version=5.0.0.0

Tags: c#, devexpress, blazor-server-side, .net-5, xaf

I am trying to create a report in DevExpress XAF Blazor .
When I set the ObjectTypeName property of the CollectionDataSource component to the name of my business class that will be displayed in my report I get this error

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

But when I use package manager console  to check latest version, I found this

```
PM> Find-Package [System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter]

Id                                  Versions                                                                                                                            
--                                  --------                                                                                                                            
System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter {4.3.0}
```

Right now, I am confused why I am getting error with version does not exist.
This is Call Stack

```
    at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
at System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes(Boolean inherit)
at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.BaseTypeInfoSource.<>c.b__5_0(Type key)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.BaseTypeInfoSource.GetOwnAttributes(Type type)
at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.BaseTypeInfoSource.InitAttributes(TypeInfo typeInfo)
at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.TypeInfo.EnsureAttributesCore()
at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.BaseInfo.EnsureAttributes()
at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.BaseInfo.d__16`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.BaseInfo.FindAttribute[AttributeType](Boolean recursive)
at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.BaseInfo.FindAttribute[AttributeType]()
at DevExpress.Persistent.Base.ReportsV2.ReportsPropertyDescriptorCollection.CreatePropertyDescriptorCore(IMemberInfo memberInfo, String name)
at DevExpress.ExpressApp.XafPropertyDescriptorCollection.CreatePropertyDescriptor(IMemberInfo memberInfo, String name)
at DevExpress.Persistent.Base.ReportsV2.PropertyDescriptorProvider.CreatePropertyDescriptorCollection(ITypeInfo pdcTypeInfo, Boolean includeInvisibleMembers)
at DevExpress.Persistent.Base.ReportsV2.PropertyDescriptorProvider.CreatePropertyDescriptorCollection()
at DevExpress.Persistent.Base.ReportsV2.PropertyDescriptorProvider.SetObjectType(String targetTypeName)
at DevExpress.Persistent.Base.ReportsV2.PropertyDescriptorProvider.TypeInfoIsValid()
at DevExpress.Persistent.Base.ReportsV2.PropertyDescriptorProvider.GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
at DevExpress.Persistent.Base.ReportsV2.CollectionPropertyDescriptorProvider.System.ComponentModel.ITypedList.GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
at DevExpress.Persistent.Base.ReportsV2.DataSourceBase.System.ComponentModel.ITypedList.GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.DataBrowserHelperBase.GetListItemProperties(Object list)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.DataBrowserHelperBase.GetListItemProperties(Object list, PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.DataBrowserHelper.GetListItemProperties(Object list, PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.DataBrowser.GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Native.Data.CustomListBrowser.GetItemProperties()
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.DataContextBase.GetItemProperties(Object dataSource, String dataMember)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.Design.PropertiesProvider.GetItemProperties(Object dataSource, String dataMember, EventHandler`1 action)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.Design.PickManagerBase.<>c__DisplayClass4_1.b__1(Object s1, GetDataSourceDisplayNameEventArgs e1)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.Design.PropertiesProvider.GetDataSourceDisplayName(Object dataSource, String dataMember, EventHandler`1 callback)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.DisplayNameProviderPickManager.GetDataSourceName(Object dataSource, String dataMember, IPropertiesProvider provider, EventHandler`1 callback)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.Design.PickManagerBase.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IEnumerator enumerator)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.Design.ActionExecutor.RunAction()
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.Design.ActionExecutor.AddAction(Action`1 action)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.Design.PickManagerBase.FillNodes(Object dataSource, String dataMember, IList nodes)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.Design.PickManagerBase.FillContent(IList nodes, Collection`1 dataSources, Boolean addNoneNode)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Native.TreeListPickManager.FillContent(IList nodes, Collection`1 dataSources, Boolean addNoneNode)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.Design.PickManagerBase.FillContent(IList nodes, IList dataSources, Boolean addNoneNode)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Native.DataSourceNativeTreeList.UpdateDataSource(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Object[] dataSources)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.FieldListTreeView.UpdateDataSource(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.FieldListController.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.b__0()
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.FieldListController.ProcessMessage(Action action)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.FieldListController.UpdateDataSource(IDesignerHost host)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.FieldListController.UpdateTreeList()
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.ReportToolWindowItemBase.UpdateView()
at DevExpress.Data.Utils.ToolShell.UpdateToolItems()
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.Native.ReportToolShell.UpdateToolItems()
at DevExpress.Design.VSIntegration.ToolShellController.ChangeToolVisibility(IToolShell toolShell, IToolShell oldToolShell)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.Native.ReportToolShellController.ChangeToolVisibility(IToolShell toolShell, IToolShell oldToolShell)
at DevExpress.Design.VSIntegration.ToolShellController.ChangeToolVisibility(IDesignerHost newDesignerHost, IDesignerHost oldDesignerHost)
at DevExpress.Design.VSIntegration.ToolShellController.designerHost_LoadComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerLoaderHost.EndLoad(String rootClassName, Boolean successful, ICollection errorCollection)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is likely another dependency in your project that references the version 5.0.0.0 of `System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter`.

Check all the dependencies of your project references

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot find any package installed with the same name 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter'

Comment: You will not have another package with the same name, but rather a package that has a dependency on `System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter` v5.0.0.0.
You should check the dependencies of each package referenced by your project